# Two concerns about this short passage written by William Trevor

Tags: single-word-requests

> Growing up in the listless nineteen-eighties, Cecilia Normanton knew her father well, her mother not at all. Mr. Normanton was handsome and tall, with **steely** gray hair brushed carefully every day so that it was as he wished it to be. His shirts and suits gave the impression of being part of him, as his house in Buckingham Street did, and the family business that bore his name. Only Mr. Normanton’s profound melancholy was entirely his own. It was said by people who knew him well **that** melancholy had not always been his governing possession, that once upon a time he had been carefree and a little wild, that the loss of his wife—not to the cruelty of an early death but to her preference for another man—had left him wounded in a way that was irreparable.

1. What substitution do you recommend for the ward steely? According to dictionaries steel gray is a nearly neutral slightly purplish dark gray that is lighter and slightly bluer. I have my doubts if the writer meant that his hair was blue gray!
2. What the highlighted **that** is reffering to in line 4 ? Is it reffering to the melancholy ? I mean does it mean **the melancholy** , or is it just an object, like other **that** s that come follwing the first one?

Comment: 1) don't think of the particular shade that 'steely gray' is on some painter's color wheel, but rather the impression it gives you of personality connected to 'steel' 2) 'that' introduces a relative clause, it is not a modifier.

Comment: @Mitch I don't think that's a relative clause there. It's just a content clause. We can paraphrase: *It was said that melancholy......... irreperable by people who knew him wel.l

Comment: @Araucaria sure. the point is that 'that' is not a determiner for melancholy or an object, it is instead introducing the rest of the sentence. One could replace 'that' with 'which' but not 'this'.

Comment: @Mitch Hmm. Not sure that quite there really: *It is said which melancholy had not always been his governing posession* doesn't seem to work very well, imo. How about for you?

Comment: @Araucaria: Yes, you're right, 'which' sounds bad there. Try another transformation "It was said that apples are red" (same semantic feel, 'that' introduces the relative clause.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost certainly meant to say "**steel gray hair**" rather than "steely gray hair".

And *melancholy* doesn't require a determiner (e.g., *the* or *that*), even though it had been brought up already. But it could have just as easily been written as "... that that melancholy". (There are already a lot of "that"s in the quoted text.)

Comment: I really can not understand how to translate this into another language. His hair was gray blue? His hair was gray like steel ? His hair was strong like steel? Thank you

Comment: His hair was gray like steel. You can go to Google Images and type in *"steel gray"* or *"steely gray"* to find the range of colors that this expression encompasses. Some of them are quite natural for hair, while others are too blue.

Comment: "Steely" means *metaphorically* resembling steel.  You can have a *steely gaze*, your gaze would be steady and unblinking, like steel; you can have a *steely resolve*, your resolve would be hard and unbending, like steel.  When something literally resembles steel, the usual adjective is just *steel*.

Answer (score 1):

*Steely* gives the impression of very dark grey. It might also be implying that the hair is wiry, stronger and stiffer like men's hair can become  as they mature. (So I'm reliably informed)

Regarding *that* in this context, it is not part of a relative clause. The word *that* here is a subordinator that we find at the front of content clauses. These are the clauses we find after verbs that report feelings opinions thoughts, speech acts and so forth:

- They think/ believe/ know/ suspect/ **that** it will be very successful.

*That*  has no meaning here, and in fact we can leave it out altogether. It is not a relative pronoun at all.

What William Trevor has done is move the content clause past the adjunct *by people who knew him* to the end of the sentence. Sentences like this would normally be organized like this:

- It was said **that he used to be happy** by his friends.

Because the content clause is very long, 52 words in fact, it fits better at the end of the sentence. If the author didn't do this it would be even more difficult to follow the sentence:

> > ***It was said*** that melancholy had not always been his governing possession, that once upon a time he had been carefree and a little wild, that the loss of his wife—not to the cruelty of an early death but to her preference for another man—had left him wounded in a way that was irreparable ***by people who knew him well*** .

Moving this content clause to the end of the sentence like this is a variation on what is sometimes called *heavy Noun Phrase shift*.

*Hope this is helpful!*

Comment: We don't do chat in answers. You must think your answer might be helpful, or you wouldn't answer. Please refrain from adding chat.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Just 'cos it's intended to be helpful doesn't mean it will be. But ok. On future posts.